# Finding points close to conic surface in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a conic surface in R3 defined by cone apex *c=(cx,cy,cz)*, cone axis *a=(ax, ay, az)*, half-apex angle *theta* and a set of points *pi=(px, py, pz)*.

I want to know which of the points *pi* lie on the conic surface (=are reasonably close).

So far I have been dealing with this using the cosine of vectors:

- I constructed vectors *vi* from cone apex to points *pi*
- I took dot product to compute the angle between vectors *vi* and cone axis *a*.
- I compared this angle to the half-apex angle *theta* and if their difference was smaller than some threshold, I said the points intersect.

This strategy seems to be creating widening cones and does not work well in my application.

I was wondering if there is another way how to find the intersecting points. For example by solving some conic inequation like "*ax*(px-cx)*...+az*(pz-cz)<*residual*" and then looking at the points with some small residual error. But I was not able to find any resources on this in 3D.

Side info: I have a huge number of points *pi* and I need an algorithm that is fast and compatible with matrix form/GPU computation.

Comment: Please use Latex : a point pi looks better under the form $p_i$ (use `$p_i$`), theta should be $\theta$ (written `$\theta$`), R3 should be $R^3$ (written `$R^3$`) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{a}$ be the **unit** vector directing the axis $\mathfrak{A}$ of the cone (the set of $\lambda \vec{a}, \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R_+}$).

Let $Q_i$ be the orthogonal projection of $P_i$ onto axis $\mathfrak{A}$. Let

$$\pi_i:=CP_i.\vec{a}$$

(dot product). It is well known (due to the fact that $\vec{a}$ has unit norm), that

$$\vec{CQ_i}=\pi_i \vec{a}.$$

Therefore the norm of the difference

$$\delta_i:=\| \vec{P_iQ_i}\|=\| \vec{CP_i}-\vec{CQ_i} \|=\| \vec{CP_i}-(\vec{CP_i}.\vec{a})\vec{a}\|$$

measures the distance from $P_i$ to axis $\mathfrak{A}$.

Ideally, if $P_i$ is on the cone, $CQ_iP_i$ is a right triangle in which we have :

$$\delta_i=\pi_i\tan \theta \tag{1}$$

But in general, we only have :

$$\delta_i \approx \pi_i\tan \theta \tag{2}$$

As a consequence, the discrepancy measure I advise you to take is :
$$\Delta_i := |\pi_i\tan \theta - \delta_i|$$

where $\Delta_i$ has to be within a certain interval $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for point $P_i$ to be selected.

(other discrepancy measures could have been proposed out of (2), but some of them would have given the pitfall you have observed in your method).

Comment: I have assumed that you consider a simple cone (opposed to a double cone). Some sign details should be re-considered in the second case.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Yes, the assumption is correct. Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, *conical surface* means something like this:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = r^2\left(\frac{z}{h}\right)^2
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
x^2 + y^2 = z^2\tan^2\alpha
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)\cos^2\alpha = z^2.
$$

So, if *master cone* is of the type:

$$
\boxed{
\left|z^2 - \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)\cos^2\alpha\right| \le 10^{-n}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\beta \le z \le \gamma \;}
$$

the *slave cone* is obtained through a *geometric transformation* of the type:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\mathbf{R}(\theta,\mathbf{\hat{w}})
\begin{bmatrix}
x-x_c \\
y-y_c \\
z-z_c \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

If $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$, $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ define a plane of normal $\mathbf{\hat{w}} \equiv \frac{\mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}}{||\mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}||}$, the *counterclockwise rotation matrix* around $\mathbf{\hat{w}}$ is:

$$
\mathbf{R}(\theta,\mathbf{\hat{w}}) = \mathbf{I} + (\sin\theta)\mathbf{W} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{W}\cdot\mathbf{W}
$$

known as *Rodrigues' Rotation Formula*, where we define the matrices:

$$
\mathbf{I} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{W} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -w_3 & w_2 \\
w_3 & 0 & -w_1 \\
-w_2 & w_1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore, the matrix that rotates $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$ to the direction of $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ is nothing but $\mathbf{R}(\arccos(\mathbf{\hat{u}}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{v}}),\mathbf{\hat{w}})$.

---

In this case, it's sufficient to set $\mathbf{\hat{u}} \equiv \frac{(a,\,b,\,c)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{v}} \equiv (0,0,1)$ to obtain:

$$
\small \boxed{
\left|\left(\frac{a(x - x_c) + b(y - y_c) + c(z - z_c)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}\right)^2 - \left((x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2 + (z - z_c)^2\right)\cos^2\alpha\right| \le 10^{-n} \, \\
\color{white}{.} \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{and} \\
\color{white}{.} \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \beta \le \frac{a(x - x_c) + b(y - y_c) + c(z - z_c)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}} \le \gamma}
$$

where in the case of *infinite cone* the last two inequalities are ignored.